# Where can I find the values of blazorweba_oidcpkce_sample:access in class AccessPolicyAttribute of BlazorWebAssemblyOidcSample.Server.Policys?

Tags: openid-connect, roles, policy, foxids, itfoxtec-identity-blazor

I cannot find the values of blazorweba_oidcpkce_sample:access issued by [FoxIDs](https://FoxIDs.com). I wonder if it should stored it in appsettings.json.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The sample client `blazorweba_oidcpkce_sample` is configured in [FoxIDs](https://foxids.com) and the client is granted the `blazorweba_oidcpkce_sample:access` scope which gives access to call the backend API. Both the frontend client and and backend resource (API) have the same name (`blazorweba_oidcpkce_sample`) in this scenarie.

The sample client request the `blazorweba_oidcpkce_sample:access` which is [configured in appsettings.json](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.BlazorWebAssembly.OpenidConnect/blob/master/samples/BlazorWAOidcSample.Client/wwwroot/appsettings.json#L8).

The API verificeres that the [access token contain the scope](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.BlazorWebAssembly.OpenidConnect/blob/master/samples/BlazorWAOidcSample.Server/Policys/AccessPolicyAttribute.cs#L17) and grant access if the scope is present.

The test user `test1@foxids.com` with password `TestAccess!` on the FoxIDs test track has two roles `role1` and `role2`.
It is possible to require e.g. `role1` in the policy like this:

```
public static void AddPolicy(AuthorizationOptions options)
{
    options.AddPolicy(_name, policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireScopeAndRoles(
            new ScopeAndRoles { Scope = "blazorweba_oidcpkce_sample:access", Roles = new [] { "role1" } }
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anders!  However, if Identity server is not able to provide authorization, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Then the request will either end on the identity server or you get back an error response in the Blazor application which results in an exception.